# Can`t compile boost spirit example4.cpp

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-lex

I am continuing to learn the Boost Spirit library and I have some issue with example that I couldn`t compile. The source of example you can find here: [source place](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/example/lex/example4.cpp). Also you can look at this code and compile result on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc874ecb7751b056).

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::spirit;
using boost::phoenix::val;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Token definition
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename Lexer>
struct example4_tokens : lex::lexer<Lexer>
{
    example4_tokens()
    {
        identifier = "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*";
        constant = "[0-9]+";
        if_ = "if";
        else_ = "else";
        while_ = "while";

        this->self = lex::token_def<>('(') | ')' | '{' | '}' | '=' | ';' | constant;
        this->self += if_ | else_ | while_ | identifier;

        this->self("WS")
            =   lex::token_def<>("[ \\t\\n]+") 
            |   "\\/\\*[^*]*\\*+([^/*][^*]*\\*+)*\\/"
            ;
    }

    lex::token_def<> if_, else_, while_;
    lex::token_def<std::string> identifier;
    lex::token_def<unsigned int> constant;
//]
};

template <typename Iterator, typename Lexer>
struct example4_grammar 
  : qi::grammar<Iterator, qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> >
{
    template <typename TokenDef>
    example4_grammar(TokenDef const& tok)
      : example4_grammar::base_type(program)
    {
        using boost::spirit::_val;

        program 
            =  +block
            ;

        block
            =   '{' >> *statement >> '}'
            ;

        statement 
            =   assignment
            |   if_stmt
            |   while_stmt
            ;

        assignment 
            =   (tok.identifier >> '=' >> expression >> ';')
                [
                    std::cout << val("assignment statement to: ") << _1 << "\n"
                ]
            ;

        if_stmt
            =   (   tok.if_ >> '(' >> expression >> ')' >> block 
                    >> -(tok.else_ >> block) 
                )
                [
                    std::cout << val("if expression: ") << _2 << "\n"
                ]
            ;

        while_stmt 
            =   (tok.while_ >> '(' >> expression >> ')' >> block)
                [
                    std::cout << val("while expression: ") << _2 << "\n"
                ]
            ;

        expression 
            =   tok.identifier [ _val = _1 ]
            |   tok.constant   [ _val = _1 ]
            ;
    }

    typedef boost::variant<unsigned int, std::string> expression_type;

    qi::rule<Iterator, qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> > program, block, statement;
    qi::rule<Iterator, qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> > assignment, if_stmt;
    qi::rule<Iterator, qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> > while_stmt;

    qi::rule<Iterator, expression_type(), qi::in_state_skipper<Lexer> >  expression;
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    typedef std::string::iterator base_iterator_type;
    typedef lex::lexertl::token<base_iterator_type, boost::mpl::vector<unsigned int, std::string> > token_type;
    typedef lex::lexertl::lexer<token_type> lexer_type;

    typedef example4_tokens<lexer_type> example4_tokens;
    typedef example4_tokens::iterator_type iterator_type;
    typedef example4_grammar<iterator_type, example4_tokens::lexer_def> example4_grammar;

    example4_tokens tokens;                         // Our lexer
    example4_grammar calc(tokens);                  // Our parser

    std::string str;

    std::string::iterator it = str.begin();
    iterator_type iter = tokens.begin(it, str.end());
    iterator_type end = tokens.end();

    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, calc, qi::in_state("WS")[tokens.self]);

    if (r && iter == end)
    {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Bye... :-) \n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it I receive a lot of errors, see full list on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc874ecb7751b056).

What wrong with this example? What and why need be changed to compile it? How identify what exactly fails compilation process?

Comment: I'm not totally sure but try adding `#define BOOST_VARIANT_USE_RELAXED_GET_BY_DEFAULT` The part of the error that actually matters is `/usr/local/include/boost/variant/get.hpp:229:5: error: static assertion failed: boost::variant does not contain specified type U, call to boost::get<U>(const boost::variant<T...>&) will always throw boost::bad_get exception`

Comment: You are completely right. When I add this define - the example could be compiled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As **Fsmv** said, the following `define` should be added:

```
#define BOOST_VARIANT_USE_RELAXED_GET_BY_DEFAULT
```

After that, the example could be compiled.